# On the iPhone and iPad, is there an app that can search a webpage or Twitter every few minutes and pop up notifications?

Tags: iphone, ipad, applications

For example, the app can be set to search on the Twitter channel https://twitter.com/itunescarddeals for a custom phrase such as "Best Buy" or "PayPal" for such sales events, every few minutes or every 30 minutes, and show a notification on the iPhone or iPad when such tweet is found.

Or equivalently, it doesn't need to be Twitter specific but can be a webpage https://twitter.com/itunescarddeals

Is there such an app?

Answer (score 3):

Use IFTTT.

(IFTTT is a cloud service sometime referred to as “If This Then That”.)

Download the IFTTT app to your phone.  I don’t see a pre-made applet that does exactly what you want, but applets are easy to create from scratch.

For your first applet, the IF trigger will be twitter “new tweet from search” and for the “THEN THAT” pick “notifications” and select “push notification from IFTTT app.

That’s enough to get you started, there are many many pre-made apps and as you see the ability to create your own using data from 100’s of services.  You really just need to log in and explore the services available.

Note:  you can also log into IFTTT.com from any browser, mobile or desktop.  (The only reason you “need” the iOS app is if you want to receive IFTTT push notifications on your phone.)

Answer (score 2):

Mentions app searches the entire internet and individual social media sites (ie twitter) for specific keywords. Only drawback is the trial period is only so long before you have to pay a  monthly fee.